# Posting Unchangeable text to twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to share some text and a link to twitter.

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+ getString(R.string.twittermessage)+" "+highscore +". "+ getString(R.string.getandroidversionhere)+" " +"&url="
                    + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordquistproductions.robberducky&hashtags=quackyquack";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

This works fine, the issue is that I am trying to post a highscore. The user can change his/her highscore once the twitter app prompts the user to post the tweet.

Any idea if its possible to add text that is not changeable in the twitter app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is not possible using Intents that call the Twitter App of the system.

Maybe you can tweet this message directly? It should be possible using the REST API and the POST statuses/update functions [1]. For this, authentication is needed - OAuth should be used for that. [2] The users can grant your App the permission for tweeting and by that the user cannot mutate the Highscores anymore ;)

[1] https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

[2] https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Comment: Thank you I will try to set it up this way.